# How to upload Image or large file to temp folder before submit form in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, jquery-file-upload

I'm using this code to upload files or images. It's working but can't upload a large file and I want to upload a file when selecting it from the local computer like the below image.
[image]

I use below PHP code in the controller.

```
$image = $request->file('file_upload');
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        echo $new_name;
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
```

Comment: If you got any error? paste it here.

Comment: The file upload failed to upload.

Comment: I try to upload 2.23MB powerpoint file

Comment: Please check the max upload size in phpinfo.

Comment: What packages are you using to upload the file? Are you using any javascript packages? And what is maximum PHP upload size, set in php.ini? Also, what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I changed max_upload size, but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code.

Change the `$request->sharing_file` with your field name.

You can increase the `$size` for image what you want, currently it is 16mb and working fine.

```
$myimage = $request->image;

$size = getClientSize();
if($sizes < 16777216){

$fileMimeType = explode('/', $myimage->getClientMimeType());
$fileType = $fileMimeType[0];

$originalFileName = substr($myimage->getClientOriginalName(), 0, strpos($myimage->getClientOriginalName(), "."));

$originalFileName = substr(str_replace(' ', '-', $originalFileName),0,10);
$rand = rand(9,1000);

$fileName = $rand.'-'.$originalFileName.'.'.$myimage->getClientOriginalExtension();

$upload = $values->move(public_path('images'), $fileName);

if($upload) {
    $message = 'File Uploaded';
} else {
    $message = "Failed to upload file";
}

}
else {
    $message = 'Files size should be less than 16 MB.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
       if ($request->hasFile('file_upload')) {
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/';
            $file = $request->file_upload;
            $fileName = time() . '.'.$file->clientExtension();
            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            $input['your_databse_table_field_name'] = $fileName;
        }
```